# Projecting attributes to indices using dynamodb mapper

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I just can't find the way to project selected attributes (not hashkey) into indices using dynamodb mapper annotations.

Consider an example:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "scores")
public class DynaScoreItem {
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    int user;
    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    int level;
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    int score;
    @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(localSecondaryIndexName = "sort_by_added")
    long added;
}
```

I just want to add score to "sort_by_added" index. How to do it using annotations?

Comment: can you explain what does: `to add score to "sort_by_added" index` mean?

Comment: I mean project the score attribute to index so that when i query index and get DynaScoreItem, it has score variable set. Now when i query index score always equals 0.

Comment: is your code sample abbreviation? From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html you can see that the DynamoDB attributes should be put above the getters.

Comment: @ChenHarel From what I can tell, all of the mapper annotations use `@Target(value={FIELD,METHOD})`, but I think you need to be consistent in a class that you should only use getters or that you only use fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attribute projections are set on index creation, and not determined by annotations (currently). There is no way to mark attributes as part of an attribute projection with annotations. Looking at the Javadoc for the [`DynamoDBMapper.generateCreateTableRequest(Class<?> clazz)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#generateCreateTableRequest(java.lang.Class)):

> Parse the given POJO class and return the CreateTableRequest for the
>   DynamoDB table it represents. Note that the returned request does not
>   include the required ProvisionedThroughput parameters for the primary
>   table and the GSIs, and that all secondary indexes are initialized
>   with the default projection type - KEY_ONLY.

The key part of this is the **default projection type - KEY_ONLY**. If you create your table using this API, you would have to specify the projections yourself.

Comment: This took hours to figure out. Thx for your reply.